# Get text from inside custom component tag

Tags: angular, components

I'm trying to get the text (with html-tags and all) that gets added in a custom component in the component itself. That way I can show it in the correct spot.
I'm not sure if it can be done, but I don't see an alternative.

Page

```
<detail [content]="content" [image]="'animals.jpg'">
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

.ts-file of component

```
export class DetailComponent 
{
  @Input() content: Content;
  @Input() image:   string;

  constructor() 
  {

  }
}
```

How can I get the 'ul' and it's children in the code of the component so I can show it in a specific spot?
Passing text through a property would make it lose it's structure.

I've tried via ElementRef, but I only get the detail-tag through nativeElement, not it's children.

Comment: 'Specific spot' - like position on the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@proti's answer was on the right track. However, since the template you need is inside (assuming there is the closing tag of `</detail>` after the `</ul>` tag) the

```
`<detail><!-- Content Needed --></detail>`
```

you have to use `@ContentChild` instead of `@ViewChild`. 
Then you can capture the 'contents' in your component in the `ngAfterContentInit()` life-cycle hook.

The template,

```
<detail [content]="content" [image]="'animals.jpg'">
 <ul #content>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
 </ul>
</detail>
```

In the component class,

```
@ContentChild('content') elemRef: ElementRef;

ngAfterContentInit() {
 // treat this.elemRef as a ElementRef type variable and do whatever you want to do with it
}
```

`ElementRef` is imported from `@angular/core`

Answer (score 0):

You can do that like that:

Set variable in HTML template for `<ul>` e.g. `#myUlVar`

Get it in TS using `@ViewChild`

```
<detail [content]="content" [image]="'animals.jpg'">
<ul #myUlVar>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>

export class DetailComponent 
{
  @Input() content: Content;
  @Input() image:   string;
  @ViewChild('myUlVar') ul: HTMLElement;
  constructor() 
  {

  }
}
```

or read more here:
http://learnangular2.com/viewChild/